# How can I configure babel/preset-env to include core-js URLSearchParams polyfill?

Tags: babeljs, babel-preset-env, core-js

I'm using `URLSearchParams` in my app. The code is transpiled with `babel`, using `babel/preset-env` and `core-js@3` to include polyfills needed for the browsers I target.

This is my babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false,
        "corejs": "3",
        "useBuiltIns": "entry",
        "forceAllTransforms": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Here is my `.browserslistrc`:

```
IE 11
Edge >= 14
last 2 Chrome versions
last 2 Firefox versions
```

The problem is that even though I've specified IE11 in `.browserslistrc`, the polyfill for `URLSearchParams` is still not included in the final bundle. So far I've solved this by manually importing `core-js/web/url-search-params.js` but I would rather that was done automatically by `babel/preset-env`.

Can I configure `babel/preset-env` somehow to include the `URLSearchParams` polyfill from core-js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm getting upvotes on the question I should probably add my answer here as well.

The problem for me was that I was adding `@babel/polyfill` next to my entrypoint in my webpack config:

```
{
  entry: {
    "my.js": ["@babel/polyfill", "my.js"]
  }
}
```

To fix my problem I removed `@babel/polyfill` from the entrypoint, and instead added the following to the top of `my.js`:

```
import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
```